# Why are coupling coefficients in codirectional coupling in an optical waveguide often real-valued?

Tags: fiber-optics

I'm reading about the Coupled-Mode Theory in optical waveguides (namely in optical fibers) and there is one piece of the puzzle which I still don't understand. Below, there is the definition of the mode coupling coefficient -or how quickly power leaks out of one waveguide into another one.

Coupling coefficient between waveguide $n$ and waveguide $m$:

$$\kappa_{nm}=\frac{\omega\epsilon_{0}\iint(n^{2}-n^{2}_{m})\mathbf{e^{*}_{n}}\cdot\mathbf{e_{m}}\,dxdy} {\iint\hat{z} \cdot (\mathbf{e^{*}_{n}} \times \mathbf{h_{n}}+ \mathbf{e_{n}}\times\mathbf{h^{*}_{n}})\,dxdy},$$

where $\omega$ is the angular frequency, $n$ is the actual index profile, $n_{m}$ is the index profile of a given core $m$ in the absence of the rest of the cores, $\mathbf{e}$ and $\mathbf{h}$ are the normalized vector core modes of the elctric and magnetic fields (respectively), and * the complex conjugate.

Regarding $x$,$y$,$z$: $x$ and $y$ represent the cross-sectional plane of the optical waveguide, and the signals propagate in the $z$ axis.

In this [Youtube video](https://youtu.be/pZ_alesCCPo), when it comes to codirectional coupling, it is said that the mode coupling coefficients are often real-valued. Also, the PhD [thesis](http://eprints.lib.hokudai.ac.jp/dspace/bitstream/2115/53864/1/Tetsuya_Hayashi.pdf) from one guy who has experimented quite a bit with these multicore fibers; shows some simulations with real-valued coefficients (p.10).

My question then is: why are they real? what are the assumptions required for this to be the case? If the electric and magnetic field are assumed to be complex-valued, how is it possible for the mode-coupling coefficients to be real?

Comment: I edited the question again because there was a complex conjugate operation  which should not have been there  in the formula.

Comment: Please have a look on this book Photonics: Optical Electronics in Modern Communications 6th Edition by Yariv. Chapter 12